# How can I use dynamic linking in a Docker image based on busybox?

Tags: docker, rust

On my Ubuntu machine, I have a http server Rust binary dynamically linked against glibc (the default target), and I want to put *my-rust-app* into the Docker busybox base image. Copying each of the libraries into busybox at `/usr/lib` didn't seem to work and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` didn't seem to work at runtime either. Do I need to pass special options to cargo at compile time?

Here's my current setup:

```
$ rustc --version
rustc 1.7.0 (a5d1e7a59 2016-02-29)
$ cargo --version
cargo 0.8.0-nightly (28a0cbb 2016-01-17)
```

**UPDATE 1:**

The build process and my linked libraries:

```
/$ cargo build --release
/$ cd target/release
/target/release$ mkdir so
/target/release$ ldd my-rust-app
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffc0b97000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f1f270d7000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f1f26eb9000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f1f26ca3000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f1f268de000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f1f27686000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f1f265d8000)
```

I copy each of those (except *linux-vdso.so* which is injected into the process at runtime):

```
/target/release$ mkdir so
/target/release$ cp /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 so/
/target/release$ cp /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 so/
/target/release$ cp /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 so/
/target/release$ cp /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 so/
/target/release$ cp /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 so/
```

My Dockerfile uses the `busybox` image at the `glibc` tag:

```
/target/release$ cat Dockerfile 
FROM busybox:glibc
EXPOSE 3000
WORKDIR /usr/bin
COPY my-rust-app .
COPY so/ /usr/lib
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib"
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/my-rust-app"]
```

Once the image *my-rust-app* is built, I try to run the app in the container:

```
/target/release$ docker run -d -p 3000:3000 --name my-rust-app my-rust-app
9aaf3c9b0e6d52511723382b5248da3c59397acca5f60637644ba311ec394d5e
```

Looking at `docker logs`, I see output from my server:

```
/target/release$ docker logs my-rust-app
Listening on port 3000
```

However, I am unable to curl the endpoint:

```
/target/release$ curl http://127.0.0.1:3000/
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

If I try to run the same *my-rust-app* directly in my Ubuntu host, I can start the server and curl it successfully:

```
/target/release$ ./my-rust-app &
[1] 6131
Listening on port 3000

/target/release$ curl http://127.0.0.1:3000/health
Got request for /health
{"status":"ok"}
```

What's wrong with my container or Rust binary?

Comment: Which version of Rust are you using? There were recent changes regarding the use of RPATH that might either help or hinder here.

Comment: @MatthieuM. added rustc and cargo version numbers. Thanks for asking!

Comment: 1.7.0 is precisely the version that activated the use of the [`RPATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath), however according to the [release notes](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#misc) it should not take precedence over the LD_LIBRARY_PATH :/

Comment: I think maybe I just don't understand how dynamic linking works. Should I be disabling or changing the RPATH at compile time to work with my container?

Comment: If your application booted inside docker, the problem is not one dynamic loading as far as I can tell.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I'm super unfamiliar with dynamic linking prior to this, so I suspect you're right. However, it's odd that my binary works outside the container but not inside. Could a different glibc be present inside the container that takes precedence over the ones copied in?

Comment: I would first note that your `curl` command differs (no `/health` at the end) but otherwise the issue might be less due to the code itself and more to the networking configuration of your Docker image? I am afraid I don't have any experience in Docker images though :/

Comment: Yay!! I have it working now. Looks like copying all the libraries into /usr/lib on a buxybox:glibc base image and setting --net=host at docker run did the trick. Thanks @MatthieuM.